# Altair interval selection in concatenated charts with 'density', 'aggregate' and 'calculate' transforms

Tags: python, selection, intervals, altair

I have two concatenated charts built on the same DF. The left one shows a density transform of one data column, the right one shows a scatter plot of aggregates of other data columns.

[image: example]

I would like to do an interval selection on the left side and filter transform the right side accordingly. No matter what I select, however, the right side loses all data points.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
source = data.iris()

brush = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])

PDFs = alt.Chart(source
).transform_density(
    'sepalWidth',
    as_=['size','density'],
    groupby=['species']
).mark_line().encode(
    x='size:Q',
    y='density:Q',
    color='species'
).add_selection(
    brush
)

Scatter = alt.Chart(source
).transform_aggregate(
    Frequency = 'count()',
    petalL_mean = 'mean(petalLength)',
    petalW_mean = 'mean(petalWidth)',
    sepalL_mean = 'mean(sepalLength)',
    groupby = ['species']
).transform_calculate(
    Value = 'datum.Frequency / (datum.petalL_mean * datum.petalW_mean)'
).mark_point().encode(
    x = 'sepalL_mean:Q',
    y = 'Value:Q',
    color='species'
).transform_filter(
    brush
)

PDFs | Scatter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Interval selection cannot be used for aggregate charts yet in Vega-Lite.](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#current-limitations) The error behavior have been updated [in a recent PR to Vega-Lite to show a helpful message.](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/7442)

Comment: ok thx, looks like I have to find another solution here. By the way it seems to be not only the case for interval selection: I changed the code as to define my upper and lower boundaries using two range bindings (sliders) with `selection_single`, but the result is the same: no points get plotted when I want to display aggregated data