# Using interval selection: manipulate what is taken into aggregation of individual encoding channels of altair

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair, vega-lite

I am making an XY-scatter chart, where both axes show aggregated data.
For both variables I want to have an interval selection in two small charts below where I can brush along the x-axis to set a range.

The selection should then be used to filter what is taken into account for each aggregation operation individually.

On the example of the `cars` data set, let's say I what to look at Horsepower over Displacement. But not of every car: instead I aggregate (sum) by `Origin`. Additionally I create two plots of totally mean HP and displacement over time, where I add interval selections, as to be able to set two distinct time ranges.
Here is an example of what it should look like, although the selection functionality is not yet as intended.

[image: chart]

And here below is the code to produce it. Note, that I left some commented sections in there which show what I already tried, but does not work. The idea for the `transform_calculate` came from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1765). But I don't know how I could use the extracted boundary values for changing what is included in the aggregations of x and y channels. Neither the double `transform_window` took me anywhere. Could a `transform_bin` be useful here? How?

Basically, what I want is: when brush1 reaches for example from 1972 to 1975, and brush2 from 1976 to 1979, I want the scatter chart to plot the summed HP of each country in the years 1972, 1973 and 1974 against each countries summed displacement from 1976, 1977 and 1978 (for my case I don't need the exact date format, the `Year` might as well be integers here).

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars.url

brush1 = alt.selection(type="interval", encodings=['x'])
brush2 = alt.selection(type="interval", encodings=['x'])


scatter = alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x = 'HP_sum:Q',
    y = 'Dis_sum:Q',
    tooltip = 'Origin:N'
).transform_filter(  # Ok, I can filter the whole data set, but that always acts on both variables (HP and displacement) together... -> not what I want.
    brush1 | brush2
).transform_aggregate(
    Dis_sum = 'sum(Displacement)',
    HP_sum = 'sum(Horsepower)',
    groupby = ['Origin']
# ).transform_calculate(  # Can I extract the selection boundaries like that? And if yes: how can I use these extracts to calculate the aggregationsof HP and displacement?
#     b1_lower='(isDefined(brush1.x) ? (brush1.x[0]) : 1)',
#     b1_upper='(isDefined(brush1.x) ? (brush1.x[1]) : 1)',
#     b2_lower='(isDefined(brush2.x) ? (brush2.x[0]) : 1)',
#     b2_upper='(isDefined(brush2.x) ? (brush2.x[1]) : 1)',
# ).transform_window(  # Maybe instead of calculate I can use two window transforms...??
#     conc_sum = 'sum(conc)',
#     frame = [brush1.x[0],brush1.x[1]],  # This will not work, as it sets the frame relative (back- and foreward) to each datum (i.e. sliding window), I need it to correspond to the entire data set
#     groupby=['sample']
# ).transform_window(
#     freq_sum = 'sum(freq)',
#     frame = [brush2.x[0],brush2.x[1]],  # ...same problem here
#     groupby=['sample']
)

range_sel1 = alt.Chart(cars).mark_line().encode(
    x = 'Year:T',
    y = 'mean(Horsepower):Q'
).add_selection(
    brush1
).properties(
    height = 100
)

range_sel2 = alt.Chart(cars).mark_line().encode(
    x = 'Year:T',
    y = 'mean(Displacement):Q'
).add_selection(
    brush2
).properties(
    height = 100
)


scatter & range_sel1 & range_sel2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Altair interval selection in concatenated charts with 'density', 'aggregate' and 'calculate' transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812223/altair-interval-selection-in-concatenated-charts-with-density-aggregate-and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Interval selection cannot be used for aggregate charts yet in Vega-Lite.](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#current-limitations) The error behavior have been updated [in a recent PR to Vega-Lite to show a helpful message.](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/7442)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your requirements correctly, does this look close to what you want? (Just added param selections on top of your vertically concatenated graphs)

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegMYWQGcA6AK0IHsA7EAXwBoQA3Xa-KeAbVAFsCBreKCgBPAA4BTDGIoBLKhwYgoyCFUIAzCsh5dQG2aigTkQkGrB6QYghF1xwswnXqgbq+yAAWYugF1aWj9GCSpWMHkAczMADzMISMjkCUjoKQdCRF1GAwlUSwcACW1CCRkAdxMXEBF4xOTU4wxM7JBc-IwAEScxVAhcCR5QxUYoCgojWV84bjbZPIKQAHlkWUj5f0DXbwk1rw44AFYABkY+ZEEEZXF0kFR5KSVQ8KjYs3bFgE0JAhBR2SGAFUqLIDjUfqYlLUrgkkik0hghmo-nMFhhikQyhRKpClO47M4ZqAqHZbj4UaVUBJcAdhDcMPJjMgmBB0IEAtsvLtIvt4CczgIzKJJBh7lRHiEwhQIlRolc4lcPhhvr9-kCQWCRBDqtDQLCGgiHEiaDl5h0HN1CL1+oNhnQ8bYeITZiShhgIs5GJTqbTriKHIyTCy2UFQ0A)